# Image filter from Timber not working for picture tag

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I am using WordPress with Timber plugin. Inside the Timber plugin, their is image filters `|towebp` and `|tojpg`. When I used them in picture tag then It is not working properly. It doe snot allow the picture to shows up on screen. I am using the following code.

```
<picture class="picture">
   <source srcset="{{Image(options.image).src|webp}}" type="image/webp">
   <source srcset="{{site.theme.link}}/static/images/6.jpeg" type="image/jpeg">
   <img src="{{site.theme.link}}/static/images/6.jpeg" alt="Alt text for the image">
</picture>
```

If I use `|towebp`, then it is not working, but without that, everything is working fine.

Comment: "*|towebp then it is not working*" - What is not working? Are you receiving an error? Did you enable debug mode to see if you get any errors?

Comment: it is not giving an error. Instead of returning URL of image. it is empty.

Comment: Did you check the permissions of the folder? I mean if application is able to generate that webp file in uploads folder?

Answer (score 0):

The maintainer [@Levdbas](https://github.com/Levdbas) provides several troubleshooting tips in this GitHub issue ticket: https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/2729.

---

> check if the Imagick PHP module is active on you (dev)server. This is needed to process images to webp. ([source](https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/2729#issuecomment-1555898761))

---

> - The url returned by Image(options.image).src, Is that http:// or https://
> - What is the field configuration of options.img (the acf field)
> - Check your home_url() settings. Does it state https:// instead of http://?
> - did you do a search/replace in the database to search for old http:// urls?

([source](https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/2729#issuecomment-1561817130))

For the asker of this question, the problem was that their `home_url` was using http instead of https. ([source](https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/2729#issuecomment-1561840893))

---

And some additional info about performance and known issues:

> The conversion only happens once at the initial pageload if there is no webp image present of the file you want to convert. After that Timber will load the earlier converted image from the file system.
>
> Please be mindful of the fact that there is a known issue in the 1.x version of Timber where the webp image is not removed properly when deleting the original media file. This should be fixed in the 2.x version where we are working on right now.

([source](https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/2729#issuecomment-1564712686))